# Why is Twitter’s Bootstrap better than the responsive, adaptive themes available for blogs and frameworks?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I’m using Drupal (please note that this is not a Drupal related question), and I can get many responsive, adaptive themes from their repositories. Many of them use HTML5 and/or CSS3. I can imagine that the same happens in Wordpress, and other products.

I would like to know why I should try to learn how to use Bootstrap. I mean, why is it better? (Is it better?) Is it because it uses [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)?

I’ve read what’s in their site, and it seems that they put a lot of interesing stuff all in one place, but I fail to see why this seems to get that much attention.

As I’m looking to change my site’s design, I thought of adapting Bootstrap into my Drupal site, but I want to be sure that’s the right thing to do in terms of SEO, loading time of the site, mobile web, etc.

Thanks for your insight!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its just another CSS Grid solution... it does however contain allot of styles for commonly used components such as buttons.

What makes it so popular is that it looks good, and is excellent for prototyping or applying a good look on tight scheduled projects where you don't care about looking unique.

I use the bootstrap mainly to create small management dashboards on low scale applications.

Answer (score 5):

I am not from drupal background. But I can tell you twitter bootstrap saves my time to use various UI components,  when compared with jquery UI and other jquery UI components.

When I chose jquery as my javascript platform I loved it. Along with jquery UI I thought my life would be simple. But when I started using jquery UI, I started using 960gs, superfish menu etc. etc for various UI needs. After few months, I realized I spent more time for these things than I expected.

Just last month I started using twitter-bootstrap for my next project, now I am really glad I chose  this. It saves time and of course 'less' makes it easy to handle css.

Now I am going to try it with phonegap/jquery mobile to see how it works.